# ZoomTo not working in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF?

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, zoom

I have a graphics layer. When the user selects an address from our software I want the map to ZoomTo that address. This works, but the user has to have an interaction for the map first. I thought this might be because the Map Extent was being reset, but when stepping though the code, it seems to Initialize first. Below is the code I am using. I separated the zooming code into another method just to see if it made a difference, but it did not. I also tried taking the extent off of "MyMap"

```
public void ShowMap(string account_num, string street, string city, string state, string zip)
        {
            Locator FindlocatorTask = new Locator("http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer");
            FindlocatorTask.AddressToLocationsCompleted += ShowMapLocatorTask_AccountToLocatonCompleted;
            FindlocatorTask.Failed += ShowMapQueryTask_Failed;
            AddressToLocationsParameters addressParams = new AddressToLocationsParameters();
            Dictionary<string, string> address = addressParams.Address;
            string formatAddress = " ";
            formatAddress = street + " " + city + ", " + state + " " + zip;

            OStreet = street;


            if (street != null)
            {
                RelatedFeatureGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                OptionsPortal.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            accountAddress = account_num; //used to find the associated meter
            RelatedAddressTextBox.Text = formatAddress;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatAddress))
                address.Add("Address", formatAddress);


            FindlocatorTask.AddressToLocationsAsync(addressParams);

        }

        private void ShowMapLocatorTask_AccountToLocatonCompleted(object sender, ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.AddressToLocationsEventArgs args)
        {

            CandidateListBox.Items.Clear();
            _candidateGraphicsLayer.ClearGraphics();

            try
            {
                AddressCandidate candidate = args.Results[0];
                Graphic graphic = new Graphic();
                graphic.Symbol = LayoutRoot.Resources["DefaultMarkerSymbol"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol;
                graphic.Geometry = _mercator.FromGeographic(new MapPoint(candidate.Location.X, candidate.Location.Y));
                graphic.Attributes.Add("Address", candidate.Address);
                string latlon = String.Format("{0}, {1}", candidate.Location.X, candidate.Location.Y);
                graphic.Attributes.Add("LatLon", latlon);
                _candidateGraphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);

                ZoomToLocation(graphic);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Address Cannot be Found", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }

        public void ZoomToLocation(Graphic graphic)
        {

            MapPoint candidatePoint = graphic.Geometry as MapPoint;
            double displaySize = MyMap.MinimumResolution * 30;

            ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Envelope displayExtent = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Envelope(
                    candidatePoint.X - (displaySize / 2),
                    candidatePoint.Y - (displaySize / 2),
                    candidatePoint.X + (displaySize / 2),
                    candidatePoint.Y + (displaySize / 2));


            MyMap.ZoomTo(displayExtent);
        }
```

No errors are being thrown.

I actually think I know what it is but I have no idea how I am going to handle it. It seems that the Initial Extent of MyMap is being set AFTER the Extent of the ZoomTo. The ZoomTo basically beats the initialize event, even though it is fired first.

I have tried wrapping the code in an "if (MyMap.IsInitialized)", but it still is a no go. HOWEVER, if I put a messagebox in the ZoomTo method that forces the user to click ok, it works every time. I really don't want to have to do that.

`Thread.Sleep` also does not work because it stops the Map from loading completely

Comment: Do you need to then call *Refresh* or *Update* on the map to say "I'm finished with my stuff, now redraw the canvas please". I have a tool that does similar in ArcMap and I have to call IActiveView.Refresh() or the map will be zoomed to the right place just not redrawn. Another possibility is that the spatial reference of the envelope may need to be set or ArcMap may just ignore it.

Comment: I actually think I know what it is but I have no idea how I am going to handle it. It seems that the Initial Extent of MyMap is being set after the Extent of the ZoomTo. The ZoomTo basically beats the initialize even though it is fired first. I have tried wrapping the code in an "if (MyMap.IsInitialized)", but it still is a no go. HOWEVER, if I put a messagebox in the ZoomTo method that forces the user to click ok, it works every time. I really don't want to have to do that. Thread.Sleep also does not work because it stops the Map from loading completely.

Comment: Also, it seems that MyMap.Extent is never changing even when assigning it to addressExtent.

Comment: Try setting the spatial reference of the envelope: *displayExtent.SpatialReference = MyMap.SpatialReference;* immediately prior to MyMap.ZoomTo(displayExtent);. I know it's a slightly different API to the ArcMap API, I encountered a similar problem before where the new extent was being ignored because the spatial reference wasn't set.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Arrrg I was so hoping that was going to work. I had actually not tried that yet, but it still did not work :( I wonder if this is something ESRI would help with.

Comment: Probably a good idea to contact Esri support if that is an option.